# Magento 2 on save configurable product from admin show product in frontend list, indexing removes

Tags: configurable-product, reindex, magento-2.1.7, simple-product, save

I've got configurable product and simple product associated to it.
when I save configurable in admin it shows in the the product listing but when I reindex e.g
`bin/magento indexer:reindex`it removes from product listing

What-the-heck is going on I can't find out if this might be a bug or something else. can anyone please help? I appreciate.

Comment: I've run the following indexer each one one separately and clean cache http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html  this 2 **catalog_category_product** and 
**catalog_product_category** are the source of the cause problem but not sure now how to identity exact issue. any help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found an answer it's 100% a Bug an there is a fix ref: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8018

It's just too bad that bugs are introduced on every release.